# cannot add p-values to my ggplot box plot

Tags: ggplot2, boxplot, p-value

I am trying to add p-values to my boxplots but I keep get this error:

`Error in is.factor(x) : object 'group' not found`

```
p_vals<- tibble::tribble(
  ~group1, ~group2, ~p,     ~y.position,
  "Sync",  "Meta",    0.0420994, 35,
  "Sync",  "Poly",    0.2497937, 30,
  "Meta",  "Poly",    0.5471125, 30)
```

## and this is my ggplot command

```
ggplot(CD4, aes(x=group,y=data,group=group, fill=as.factor(group), outlier.colour="red")) + stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar', width = 0.2) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.75,outlier.shape = NA, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_point(aes(fill=group),pch=21,size=2,colour="black",position = "jitter", show.legend = FALSE, alpha = 10)+
  ggtitle("CD4_naive") +
  labs(x = "Group",y="% of CD4+ T cells") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format(accuracy = 1))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#29ada0", "#f7bb25", "#E71D36"))+
  theme_prism(base_size = 9) +
  add_pvalue(p_vals)
```

The only problem is with the last line in the command, could you please help me? is it related to the tibble or the names?

Comment: It's expecting the same columns in the `p_vals` dataframe and the `CD4` dataframe. Try `add_pvalue(p_vals, inherit.aes = FALSE)` (though cant test this without your data).

Comment: Hello Andy, thank you for the comment, the p-values are added with your command but the boxplots are 0 now

Comment: oh now it worked when I changed the y.position number from 30 to 0.3, the y scale has changes to 3000% when I added you comments but now it looks fine thank you

Comment: Glad it helped! rescaling over %s/proportions sometimes catches me out too!